# Nativescript Vue: Getting item in array from itemTap in ListView

Tags: nativescript-vue

I am trying to get the object on itemTap in a ListView.  I want to be able to have access to the `name` and `age` of the object.  But I can't figure out how to do this in the `onItemTap` function

**data**

`listOfItems: [{name: "Tom", age: 55}, {name:"Greg", age: 32}]`

**template**

```
<ListView for="item in listOfItems" @itemTap="onItemTap($event)">
  <v-template>
    <Label :text="item.text" />
  </v-template>
</ListView>
```

**methods**

```
onItemTap: function(args) {
  ???
}
```

Comment: Any updates, news?

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/)

`Template`

```
<ListView for="item in listOfItems" @itemTap="onItemTap">
  <v-template>
    <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
    <Label :text="item.text" />
  </v-template>
</ListView>
```

`Methods`

```
onItemTap(event) {
  console.log(event.index)
  console.log(event.item)
}
```